# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, actionbarsherlock

I'm building PageTurner in eclipse. And integrating it with Maven and ActionBarSherlcok.
But i'm getting this one single error in POM.xml.

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.1:generate-sources (execution: default-
 generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)

Comment: Do you have m2e-android installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guy, before install m2-android in Eclipse.

After in the Eclipse click with button right in the your project > Maven > Update Project.